# What is the node package to create HDI cluster and VM, etc in Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, package, npm-install

I am developing a single node js application which will create/delete a cluster and also a VM in Azure.

What is the preferred node package create HDI cluster and VM, etc in Azure?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure

Comment: @GauravMantri I don't find a example to create a HDInsight cluster using azure package. Do you know any?